# Find My on my MacBook Pro refuses to locate my AirTags, is there a way to clear its cache or something?

Tags: macos, find-my, airtag

I have a few AirTags. They show up fine on my iPhone and iPad but on my MacBook Pro M2 they say "No location found". I have an older Intel MacBook Pro and they show up fine there.

Same account on all of the devices. Only account actually.

So I'm wondering if maybe I can reset the data or cache on the "Find My" app on OS X, is that possible?

Edit: I created a new user on my Mac, logged into the same icloud and it has no issues. I went back to my normal account and it can now find airtags near it but it can't find airtags that are somewhere else while my iPad sitting next to me can do it just fine and the other user account on my Mac can also do it.

Edit: I've spent hours on the phone and chat with Apple support and they don't really know what the issue is.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check `~/Library/Application\Support` and `~/Library/Containers` for anything related to Find My.

Lastly, clear `~/Library/Caches`.

Comment: On `Caches` there are some Find My packages listed but I can't delete them, even if I kill Find My processes or use `sudo`.

Comment: Looks like `bypass` doesn't exist anymore.